# extJS 4. pagination question

Tags: javascript, extjs4

Is it possible to load all data recors to the store but display only one page in the grid? I mean, using pagination I can load only one set of data at once and to show next page in the grid I have to load next set of data. I would like to load all data from the server but display only part of it.

Answer (score 2):

use Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy in ext/examples/ux/data/PagingMemoryProxy.js

Comment: PagingMemoryProxy is exact what I need. but there is one problem: As I understood, PagingMemoryProxy works only with local, inline data. how can I get the same but getting data by Ajax?

Comment: maybe u had to extend Proxy to get what u want

Comment: or not using Ajax, but use Model.load,then fill them into store.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this myself, so I'm not sure if it'll work, but you could try setting the following config values for your store:

```
buffered: true,
purgePageCount: 0//never purge the cache
```

Also, you MAY need to set `clearOnPageLoad` to false.

Also, the store has the following methods: `prefetch()` and `prefetchPage()`.

Comment: I think this maybe what u want. had anyone tested?

Answer (score 0):

> By default all data will load to Store. And if you are using
>   pagingtoolbar in the grid, it works as you want.

Comment: pagingtoolbar does not limit the set of records. the Grid shows as many records as were loaded to the store

Comment: have you tried pageSize??  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging